# Representative search results for Google?

Tags: discussion, search, google, profile-picture

Google offers the way to show the Google+ Avatar on any Google Result.

Currently I'm thinking about if it would be a nice feature, if the Avatar of the guy providing the "accepted" Answer for a question would get this additional Reward, to be displayed in the google-search-results along with his google-avatar?

**Expected Solution**

(imagine I would have given the accepted answer to that question)

[image: Description]

**Technical Requirements**

This display state can be achieved by simple providing a (hidden) Link to the Google+ profile of the avatar. However, the user would need to validate that he is *owning* the site stackoverflow.com - which is impossible.

The second possibility is to validate your *ownership* using an email-address that matches the domain - so `@stackoverflow.com`. This could be created for every user, so actually that shouldn't be a problem. (If a user decides to validate his posts, of course)

*IF* a user is validated, and the Google-Crawler will find the Term "by {GooglePlusName}" on a page, Google will display the Avatar along with the search result. (this term can be in a hidden span, div or whatever)

I don't know, if this would be possible at all (it might not be the way, Google expects this feature to work) or if that's even accepted and desired by the users/operators of stackoverflow.

However I think it would be a pretty awesome feature, that no other site has. Also one can find solutions faster. If I would see a "BalusC-Avatar" beneath a search result, I would know, that the answer is in *there* :D

Comment: I don't know what anyone's avatar looks like, it would all just be noise as far as I'm concerned. I'd say low priority at best

Comment: Well of course i dont know the avatars of every user. One could also couple that additional "feature" to like 250.000 reps or something. (The Google+-Reward-Batch) For the top-contributors I know the avatar I'd say.

Comment: I think that would confuse a lot of people, as some avatars only make sense to the SE users.  Imagine if you weren't familiar with SE and you saw BoltClock's A Unicorn's avatar next to the results?!?

Comment: @JohnnyBones that's right. If they are not the same avatars, that's bad... (Well, SE-Avatar could be fetched from G+, if the user enables the feature) - okay no excuses: Didn't think about that :P

Comment: IMO, avatars are just ice cream on top of a community driven site. You don't really _need_ it per say, but it helps with member personalization. I don't really see how personalization is needed in a google search though, sorry.

Answer (score 4):

This seems like it would cost an awful lot of time and resources, for no discernible advantage.

Possible disadvantages:

- Noise... People come to SO for questions and more importantly answers, anything drawing attention away from the valuable information, like cute little pictures, is static not signal.
- Server weight... I would imagine that this feature would tax resources quite a bit. With nearly 6 million questions, adding images to the search results for each would likely be heavy.
- Many users have down right silly avatar images:

[image] [image] [image] [image] [image]
<sup>(images have been used without permission, links to profiles not included to protect the guilty)

If you have a silly avatar image feel free to add it in</sup>

Possible Advantages

- ???

What would be the point of having someone's avatar appear in search results?